# PayPal sandbox requests are slow, are the live site requests faster?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

This site http://api-status.com/6404/117324 is currently reporting a sandbox HTTP response at 1.8 seconds. At this rate I'm quite worried that after doing any more than 2 PayPal requests that my client connection may timeout (I've had to change my timeouts in order to test). Is the live site any faster?

Is there a similar performance reporting site for the live site/requests?

I've seen plenty of posts referencing their twitter account but it doesn't seem to have any useful info for developers.

Comment: so are the live transactions faster? testing it too and i also feel like the sandbox calls are really slow.

Comment: Nobody seems to be talking about this but I find Paypal *live* checkouts and transactions unacceptably slow as well. On average our customers are waiting the order of 2-3 seconds for the interface to load, and that's with "express" checkout. But apparently no one gives a shit? Pretty sure it's not a problem on our end because just about everything else, including other third party payment processors, load very quickly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The PayPal sandbox is for functional testing only. Load testing and latency testing that mirrors live is not available.

(The PayPal live site is a discreetly separate environment, run on different cloud servers, with different capacity considerations)

In any case, PayPal checkout and transaction requests are executed in *parallel*, so cumulative delays from PayPal API endpoints will never be an issue unless you are specifically waiting for responses and running everything in series/synchronously.

Comment: Ok, thanks I'm happy that I don't need to worry about timing out then.

It seems silly to have such slow performance when this is the environment that developers test their software with (which makes them look worse than they are).

Comment: Is it normal to have this same experience with live transactions? PayPal live express checkout is unbearably slow for us, see my comment above.